# How to transfer array/dictionary to other viewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

I got an array/dictionary needs to transfer from `viewController1` to `viewController3`. 
Save it into plist or `NSUserDefault` is too complicate, and I want to find a more effective way to deal with it.
Do guys have any suggestion for it?
Thanks for your prompt helped in advance.

**Resolution:**
Finally I found out a way to fix the transfer, which is most effective way I think.
Firstly, we create a singleton class and make a method for saving the array/dictionary.
Then, declare an array object in *.h file. 
Next step, call this singleton method to save your array.
Last step, call the method and you'll get your data~

It seems working pretty well. We don't need to transfer data view to view anymore, cooll~

Comment: Write it out to a file from one VC and then read it in in the other.

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface ViewController3 : UIViewController

//Add a public property for your ViewController3
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *nameArray;

@end


// transfer it like this
NSArray *nameArray = @[@"Green", @"Gordan"];
ViewController3 *viewController3 = [[ViewController3 alloc] init];
viewController3.nameArray = nameArray;
```

Comment: wow, thanks. It looks worked well.

Comment: By using this solution we need to assign viewController3 to viewController2 at first. Like below: ViewController2 *viewController2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] init]; viewController2.viewController = viewController3;        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

Comment: But in your question description you just mention the array/dictionary you want to transfer from `viewController1` to `viewController3`. If you need to transfer view controller. It's also OK.

Comment: there've viewController2 between 1 and 3. Views pushing 1 -> 2 ->3, so that we need to transfer array from 1 to 2 and 2 deliver to 3 in regularly, which is too much work needs to do.

Comment: Is your viewController1 the root view controller? If it is, you can get the array like this:`appDelegate.window.rootViewController.nameArray`

Answer (score 0):

This is easy. Declare a NSDictionary pointer variable in `viewController3` and then assign it.